# jQuery datepicker can't read value using .val() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I've read several stackoverflow posts on how to get the value from the datepicker field. I found out that there are two methods to do that:

```
 var method1 = $('#dateInput').datepicker('getDate'); 
 var method2 = $('#dateInput').val();
```

However, method2 gives me an empty string. Why is that so? I know that .val() is a method that will get the value of the element.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/Issaki1/wun8Lomg/1/

Comment: what if you do  `$('#dateInput input').val()` ?

Comment: Hi @RaviMariya, your method works! May I know the explanation behind it? You can add the explanation as your answer and I will accept it

Comment: I might not be the best person to explain but I see that `$('#dateInput')` was returning div with no property value where `$('#dateInput input')` return input with property value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your method 2 code like below because in your HTML dateInput as id refers to the div and not actual input text. So you can target input text like below:

```
var method2 = $('[name="dateInput"]').val();
```

Or

```
var method = $('#dateInput input').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the below line

```
var method2 = $('#dateInput input').val();
```

Reason what i suspect is `<div>` has the `id="dateInput"`  and the text box has the same `id="dateInput"`.
So if we specify which object to consider then it is resolved.